# How to send additional parameters to remote script in jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

To the best of my knowledge, when a remote script is specified as the source in the set of Autocomplete options, that script receives whatever the user has typed until that point, and then it's up to that script to send relevant data based on that. Is it possible to send any additional parameter to that script? For example, suppose the site is providing the user an option to filter questions by forum. Each forum has plenty of sub-forums. Say **abc** is a forum, which contains sub-forums **bcd** ,**cde** and **def**. Now if the user has already inputted **abc**, and then he types **b**, the script should not return **bcd**, since **abc** being present ensures that **bcd** is present. So the script should return other results that start with **b**. For that I need to send a parameter to the script (having the value **abc**) such that it doesn't return results that belong to forum **abc**, and search other forum or subforum names that start with **b**. How can I send the additional parameter?

Comment: You can send anything to the remote data source. See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: Ummm, right. Stupid of me to post without studying all the examples. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - happens all the time :)